# Installing ECW for QGIS in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, references, ecw

I have followed various online help guides on how to make ecw for QGIS 1.8 work in Ubuntu 12.04. I had it all working in Ubuntu 10.04 but since migration to 12.04 no such luck.

Is there a guide that works for Ubuntu 12.04?

At the moment it seems easier to install the windows version where ecw support is included in the install, but I would like to stay with Ubuntu.

Comment: [Installing (lib)gdal-ecw][1] doesn't do the trick?


  [1]: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/quantum-gis-and-ecw-images

Comment: Well done Luke, it works perfect on my x64 Ubuntu 13.04 Raring on QGIS 1.80! ;-)

Comment: I get gdal-ecw-build: command not found

Comment: The answers given do not work for newer versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 9):

ECW libraries are not open source software and cannot be freely distributed. You need to add manually the ecw support in your local copy of gdal. On ubuntu do this:

```
wget http://de-mirror.org/distro/gentoo/distfiles/libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
unzip libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
cd libecwj2-3.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/ 
sudo ldconfig
```

Answer (score 7):

The Intergraph [ECW JPEG2000 SDK v5.0](http://geospatial.intergraph.com/products/other/ecw/ERDASECWJPEG2000SDK/Downloads.aspx) has been [released](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-ECW-JPEG2000-SDK-v5-0-now-available-td5066344.html) and includes linux support.  The ubuntugis-unstable ppa has been [updated](http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/ticket/34) to include SDK v5.0 support in libgdal-ecw-src.

Notes:

- As at 27 July 2013 build fails on [32bit Ubuntu](http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/ticket/34#comment:18)
- ECW/JP2ECW drivers fail using [Python bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/ubuntugis/ticket/34#comment:14), gdal executables work fine.
- This SDK is licensed for Desktop use only and has been [reported to fail](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/76576/2856) if attempting to use it in a Server application.

To get the ECW JPEG2000 SDK v5.0 working in ubuntu 12.04 - 13.04 64bit:

- update (or install) libgdal-ecw-src from the [UbuntuGIS Unstable PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable/)
- download the SDK installer (ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.0.bin)
- make it executable (`chmod +x ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.0.bin`)
- run it (`./ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.0.bin`)
- copy the SDK directory to /usr/local (`sudo cp -r ecwjp2_sdk /usr/local/`)
- symlink libNCSEcw.so to /usr/local/lib (`sudo ln -s /usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk/lib/x64/release/libNCSEcw.so /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so`)
- update ldconfig (`sudo ldconfig`)
- run the gdal-ecw-build script (`sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk`)
- test it works:

  `gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw`

  `ECW (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.0)`

  `JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.0)`

Comment: To use python bindings this is a workaround that worked for me:

1. Install SDK 5.0 library in ecwjp2_sdk directory;

2. Compile gdal library from source with the following syntax:

  . / configure - with-python = yes - with-ecw = / path/to/SDK/ecwjp2_sdk

Comment: Yes it should, for completeness. For me there is no problem if you want to update the answer.

Comment: By now, the SDK has switched to 5.1. I described an updated workflow for Ubuntu 14.04 here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04. For 12.04, you don't have to download the build script manually, apt-get install will work.

Answer (score 3):

[The how-to linked here](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2013/howto-install-qgis-with-ecw-support-on-linux) is the only one that worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 32bit and the latest version of QGIS.

Here I reproduce the steps, with the corresponding adjustments:

1. Go to http://download.intergraph.com/ and select "ECW Products" from the drop-down list under "Product Family:".
2. Click on "ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK v5.3 (Linux)" (version 5.3 available from 2016-06-14) and then click on "Download Now"
3. You have to register with the website.
4. Unzip the downloaded file, e.g.:

```
unzip erdas-ecw-sdk-5.3.0-linux.zip
```

5. Make the unzipped binary executable:

```
chmod +x ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.3.0.bin
```

6. Execute the program; select option "Desktop read-only"

```
./ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.3.0.bin
```

7. Now copy the `ERDAS_ECWJP2_SDK-5.3.0` folder to `/usr/local`:

```
sudo cp -r ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.2.1 /usr/local/
```

8. Locate `libNCSEcw.so` and create a symbolic ("soft") link to it. Use folder `x86` or `x64` according to your system:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.2.1/Desktop_Read-Only/lib/x86/release/libNCSEcw.so /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so
```

9. Now run the following commands (update dynamic links, install ECW GDAL extension and run it):

```
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt-get install libgdal-ecw-src
sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.2.1/Desktop_Read-Only
```

10. Confirm that everything worked:

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw
```

You should get something like

```
    ECW (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.3)
    JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.3)
```

11. Now you can run QGIS to import ECW files on a raster layer.

Very soon I should be able to report how it worked on Ubuntu 16.04 64bit, but please comment or edit this answer if you did it already.

Comment: Which GDAL version did you use, and any need for ubuntugis packages?

Comment: I had the ubuntugis and qgis repositories installed from long before, so I am not really sure which packages, if any, from ubuntugis are required. As for the GDAL version, it turns out I have ``gdal-bin 1.10.0-1~precise2``, installed 2012-03-15, ``libgdal1-1.7.0 1.7.3-6ubuntu3`` installed 2012-05-09, etc. ``libgdal-ecw-src`` was installed, obviously, just recently, and it's version 1.10.0.

Comment: So you will be out of luck on a new, clean system, since you get GDAL 2.1.0 by default, but the libgdal-ecw-src is not available for anything newer than GDAL 1.10 for precise. I made a workaround for trusty and GDAL 1.11 at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04, but that lacks python support already,