# SID and/or ECW support on QGIS for Linux

Tags: qgis, gdal, android, ubuntu, mrsid

Running QGIS on Ubuntu 11.04 and QGIS for Android on Galaxy Tab 10.1 (which is an awesome project by the way)

NEED to figure out a way to get SID and/or ECW files loaded.

Saw some posts about compiling GDAL manually but haven't had any luck.

Has anyone successfully accomplished this?

Comment: How far have you gotten attempting to compile GDAL?

Comment: Despite the assurances above, I've yet to see any explanation on how to add SID files into QGIS 8.0 on Ubuntu 12.04. If anyone has more precise information I'd also be interested to know. I've also posed a similar question in Ubuntu Forums at
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1997284 2 months, and as yet not a single response...

Comment: Those explanations do explain how to get ECW support but now how to get SID support. I've also tried manually building gdal with mrsid without any luck and have yet to find any post anywhere where anyone has done so.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good explanations around. Try:

[stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/ecw-for-qgis-1-8-in-ubuntu-12-04)
or
[qgis-user maillist](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2010-May/008647.html)
or
[Arias Prado's blog](http://ariasprado.name/2011/02/27/gdal-ecw-support-via-plugins.html#.UAmqk1sz9Kg)