# Qgis crash when I attempt to open ECW raster format.

Tags: qgis, raster, ecw

I added Ubuntugis unstable repo and installed Qgis, libgdal-ecw-src, libecwj2-3.3 but still do not work.

When I attempt to open an ecw file with Qgis it crash and tells me that there are problems with this libraries:

> /usr/local/lib/libNCSUtil.so.0.0.0
>     /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so.0.0.0
>     /usr/local/lib/libNCSCnet.so.0.0.0

I am using ubuntu 12.10 and when I do:

```
gdalinfo --formats|grep -i ecw
```

it seems to work.

```
ECW (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: can you gdalinfo the ecw file in question? can gdalinfo read it?

Comment: How can i run gladinfo to read a file?

Comment: No, it is the output: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create

Comment: Qgis 1.8 compiled with gdal 1.10.0

Comment: it seems gdal cannot find the appropriate libraries for ECW. Can you open a console, write `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/` and then run qgis from the same terminal (usually with `qgis`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ECW/JPEG2000 SDK v3.3 is very buggy. More often with JP2's but I've had numerous crashes with ECWs as well.  The [new v5.0 SDK](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-ECW-JPEG2000-SDK-v5-0-now-available-td5066344.html) should be much more robust. Try uninstalling 3.3 and [installing the v5.0 SDK](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66465/2856).

Comment: I had install v 5 SDK following this post "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/ecw-for-qgis-1-8-in-ubuntu-12-04"

Comment: but version 3 persist, how to unistall it?

Comment: @gaia `sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libNCS*` and `sudo rm  /usr/local/include/*.h` then [reinstall](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/66465/2856) the v5.0 SDK.

Comment: sudo gdal-ecw-build "/usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk grep: /usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk/include/ECW.h: File o directory non esistente /usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk seems not containing an ECW SDK 3.3"

Comment: @gaia Sounds like you didn't follow the instructions to update the libgdal-ecw-src package.  Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: You are my god!

Comment: Give me some point so as to define your post useful please.