# Error .ecw is not a supported raster data source

Tags: qgis, raster, ubuntu, ecw

I have recently installed QGIS 2.0 in my computer which has Ubuntu 13.04 and when I try to use an .ecw file it says:

> Error, .ecw is not a supported raster data source.

I am new in Linux and in QGIS, so could you help me and explain what could I do step by step?

Answer (score 1):

By default QGIS doesn't support .ecw format (Compressed Satellite Imagery).For ECW support you need to download [ecw plugin](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/archive) for QGIS for mac and to do it on Ubuntu you can follow instructions on http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2010-May/008647.html

Comment: I have a problem... QGIS 2.0 installs gdal 1.9, not the 1.7.2 like it says in the instructions link

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice post from faunalia describing a step-by-step guide on how to add ECW support in windows (for gdal-1.9.2):

http://www.faunalia.pt/node/438

---

If you've added the ubuntugis-unstable repository you can add ecw support by installing the corresponding library:

`$ sudo apt-get install libgdal-ecw`

---

To add the ubuntugis repository:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable`

(don't forget to `$apt-get update` to refresh your lists)

---

Qgis uses gdal library to read/write rasters. To see if gdal can read/write in any format run the following:

`$ gdalinfo --formats | sort`

(you pipe the output to the sort command, which sorts the out put in alphabetical order)

---

The reason qgis cannot read ecw by default, as said by `Giovanni Manghi` is:

> ECW libraries are not open source software and cannot be freely
>   distributed. You need to add manually the ecw support in your local
>   copy of gdal. On ubuntu do this

:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27398/6711