# Uninstall ERDAS ECW/JP2 SDK Version 5.0 (Ubuntu)

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, erdas-imagine, ecw

I am using Ubuntu Linux as main OS when it comes to geoprocessing but I am not yet an expert using it. I recently needed QGIS to have ECW support, so I followed the instructions of Luke in the following question and got it working.

[ECW for QGIS 1.8 in Ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/ecw-for-qgis-1-8-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Now I discovered that I keep getting following error message when doing python geoprocessing which involves any GDAL features

ERROR 1: /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.10/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW1.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI14GDALPamDataset

It doesn't affect the outcome of the script or crashes it, but it is annoying to get the terminal spammed with this error message during the usage of the script.

Is there a solution for that? If not, could anybody guide me through the uninstall process?
Note to myself: temporary stuff always in a VM ;)