# Unable to install ECW support on lubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ecw

I try unsuccessfully to install the ECW support (mainly to use ECW file in QGIS 2.2).
We attempt to follow and adapt the howto provided by [makina-corpus](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2013/howto-install-qgis-with-ecw-support-on-linux). 
My first supprise was the repository ubuntugis-unstable is unavailable for trusty and the repository http://qgis.org/debian doesn't have libgdal-ecw-src package.
Finally in desperation we add ubuntugis-unstable for the raring distribution in source.list.

And apply the following commands

```
chmod +x ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1.bin
./ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1.bin # Select option desktop read only
sudo cp -r ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1 /usr/local/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1/Desktop_Read-Only/lib/x86/release/libNCSEcw.so /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so
sudo ldconfig
sudo apt-get install libgdal-ecw-src
sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1/Desktop_Read-Only
```

The ECW format seems to be installed

```
gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw
  ECW (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.1)
  JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.1)
```

But .... Gis crash when a ECW raster file is open with the following message :

```
QGIS died on signal 4Abandon (core dumped)
```

If anyone have an idea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By now, ubuntugis-unstable has added trusty packages for QGIS 2.2 and GDAL 1.11. Unfortunately, libgdal-ecw-src is still missing, and the available versions for raring and precise are intended for GDAL 1.10.

However, I got it working (with some help from the qgis user mailing list):

1. Add ubuntugis-unstable for trusty to the sources list, or Ubuntu Software center
2. Install QGIS 2.2, GDAL 1.11 and libgdal-dev
3. Make sure QGIS is working
4. Download the ERDAS ECW SDK 5.1 for Linux from http://download.intergraph.com/
5. Open a terminal window and enter

> ```
> chmod +x ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.1.1.bin
> ./ECWJP2SDKSetup_5.1.1.bin #Select desktop-read-only and accept the license)
> sudo cp -r ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1 /usr/local/
> sudo ln -s /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1/Desktop_Read-Only/lib/x64/release/libNCSEcw.so /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so
> sudo ldconfig
> ```

To avoid version conflicts, we do not install libgdal-ecw-src with apt-get, but fetch it manually and extract it:

> ```
> wget https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntugis-unstable/+files/libgdal-ecw-src_1.10.0-1~precise4_all.deb
> ar vx libgdal-ecw-src_1.10.0-1~precise4_all.deb
> tar -xzf data.tar.gz
> sudo cp usr/src/libgdal-ecw-1.10.0.tar.gz /usr/src/
> sudo cp    usr/bin/gdal-ecw-build /usr/bin/
> sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1/Desktop_Read-Only
> ```

GDAL from ubuntugis is 1.11, but the script stores the plugin into `/usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.10`, hence it is not found by gdalinfo.

So I created a subfolder 1.11 and copied the .so file into it:

> ```
>  sudo mkdir /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.11
>  cd /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.10
>  cp gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.so /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.11
> ```

Now you can run:

> ```
>  gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ECW 
>  ECW (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.1)   
>  JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.1)
> ```

The SDK folder has a `testdata` subfolder with some samples, which should work with QGIS (also on Windows and Ubuntu 12.04).

---

**UPDATE 09-2015**

It seems that my workaround does **not** work with newer versions of ubuntu. There is no gdal package yet available at ubuntugis for vivid (15.04). Utopic (14.10) might be the latest to work, but I have not tested it.

---

**UPDATE 02-2019**

For Ubuntu 16.04 and newer, you might follow [How to get ECW support on QGIS 2.16 - Ubuntu 16.04?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209179/how-to-get-ecw-support-on-qgis-2-16-ubuntu-16-04/283201#283201) and [Can't install support for ECW in QGIS 3.6 / 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/313388#313388)

Comment: Thank you for the answer it's working perfectly. Just for information first I try with raring's libgdal-ecw package (that I suppose to be up to date) but  it's seems to be not found by gdalinfo.

Comment: There's a stray space in the symbolic link step before "/libNCSEcw.so". I can't remove it because apparently fixing just one character is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helpful answer (I upvoted). One note: I am using Linux Mint 17.1 (Rebecca) based on Trusty, and I had to copy the gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.so to /usr/local/lib/gdalplugins/1.11/ (in stead of /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.11/). Works great now with gdal 1.11 and QGIS 2.18 (Wien)

Comment: I confirm the 5.2.1 SDK does not work with the libgdal-ecw sources above. The only working version I have been able to run is built using libecwj2 (v3.3 from https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libecwj2/),  libgdal-ecw (v1.10.0-4 from http://repo.yume.ru/unstable/libgdal-ecw_1.10.0-4_amd64.deb), gdal-bin package (v1.11.3).

Comment: Thanks, AndreJ: Helped me with QGIS 2.12 running on Mint 17.2

Answer (score 1):

I think that ubuntugis repository does not match exactly the OS version. Perhaps you could try to install Qgis from a stand-alone version, but I'd rather do the downgrade of the OS version and install the right ubuntugis repository version

Comment: Your right, I just wanted to try the new ubuntu LTS, Unfortunately I will downgrade my OS. But I wonder why ubuntugis is not available for trusty.

Comment: That it is because the development of the various packages is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently It's working with raring package according to this message https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu@lists.osgeo.org/msg00829.html#.

I think my problem is related to 32bit. After downgrading to  xubuntu 12.04, I was unable to compile the SDK 5.0 (libtool wasn't reconize). With SDK 5.1 it's seems to work : the command gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ecw return

```
ECW (rw+): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 5.1)
JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 5.1)
```

But Qgis still crash when I try to open ECW file with the following message :

```
The crashed program seems to use third-party or local libraries:
 /usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk/lib/x86/release/libNCSEcw.so.5.1.1
```

Comment: Does it help to use the x64 version instead of x86?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux Mint 17, you could encounter this error:

```
ERROR 1: libNCSEcw.so: cannot open shared object file:...
```

In this case, manually add this line /usr/local/lib/release in /etc/ld.so.conf by running

```
sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a ubuntugis ppa in /etc/apt/sources.list -> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu raring main

Update source list -> sudo apt-get update

Install -> sudo apt-get install libgdal-ecw-src

See on this post 
http://muhammadbaihaqi-martin92.blogspot.com/2014/05/install-ecw-support-qgis-220-valmiera.html

Comment: Sorry, your advice does not work on Ubuntu 14.04. It requires a repository named trusty.

Comment: You mush use this repository, Because libgdal-ecw-src nothing in trusty main, you can see on http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgdal-ecw/

Comment: I know, but cross-version-building still makes some problems: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Issues-building-ECW-JP2ECW-driver-as-a-plugin-on-Ubuntu-td5156322.html