# How do I add and view *.ecw raster images in QGIS 2.2.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: qgis-2, ubuntu, ecw

How do I make ECW files work in Quantum GIS on my Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Solved in http://muhammadbaihaqi-martin92.blogspot.com/2014/05/install-ecw-support-qgis-220-valmiera.html

Comment: @Martin  - Be careful! Ubuntugis repository specified in your link is for a previous version of Ubuntu. Something may not work.

Comment: @MickyInTheSky - you are right, it does not work on Ubuntu 14.04. We have to wait until ubuntugis has a repository for trusty.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04

Comment: You mush use this repository, Because libgdal-ecw-src nothing in trusty main, you can see on http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgdal-ecw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now, wating for ubuntuGIS repository updating for "trusty", I'd advise this procedure (python must be already installed):

1. Download (after "sign up") the SDK 5.0 from [here](http://download.intergraph.com/?ProductName=ERDAS%20ECW/JPEG2000%20SDK);
2. Be careful to the licence;
3. Install/compile the SDK in a directory (e.g./usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk);
4. Download GDAL/OGR source from [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource);
5. Install/Compile GDAL with the following syntax:

   ```
   .`/configure --with-python=yes --with-ecw=/usr/local/ecwjp2_sdk`
   ```
6. Install Qgis from standalone version or from source;

That's all!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind installing [gvSIG](http://www.gvsig.com/en/products/gvsig-desktop/downloads) like I did on my Linux Mint, you will be able to read ECW files and then export them as TIFF. I had no problem reading these new TIFF's in QGIS.