# Problems installing libgdal-ecw package

Tags: qgis, error, ubuntu, ecw

I have problems to visualize ecw files for qgis 2.3.0 using ubuntu 12.04 LTS. From terminal, following the instructions for qgis 1.8 found at [ECW for QGIS 1.8 in Ubuntu 12.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/ecw-for-qgis-1-8-in-ubuntu-12-04), because launching the command `sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/`.
I added the repository `ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable` and then did these steps:

```
wget http://de-mirror.org/gentoo/distfiles/libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
unzip libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
cd libecwj2-3.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo gdal-ecw-build /usr/local/
```

Launching the last command I receive some warnings like this:

```
ecwdataset.cpp:1501:15: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’ [-Wwrite-strings]
```

and then an error message:

```
/usr/local/include/gdal_priv.h:225:19: error: ‘char**
GDALOpenInfo::papszSiblingFiles’ is private
ecwdataset.cpp:2526:48: error: within this context
```

Finally (in Italian because I have an Italian version of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS):

```
make: *** [ecwdataset.o] Errore 1
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try up-to-date instructions e.g. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94917/how-do-i-add-and-view-ecw-raster-images-in-qgis-2-2-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: A better instruction would be at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04. You have probably GDAL 1.11 installed, but the libgdal-ecw package is only compiled for GDAL 1.10. I found a workaround for that.

Comment: Can you add the repositories and the steps you did, and the error message you got? You can still edit your question for that.

Comment: thanks Andre I added the errors and warnings.Yes, I added the repository suggested ( ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable). How can I check the GDAL version installed on my system?

Comment: `gdalinfo --version` reports the gdal version. You used the old 3.3 SDK, while I was successful with the 5.1 SDK (no configure and make for that, but no write access on ecw files). I got some wanrings too, but not that error. Maybe your GDAL is too new for the SDK.

Comment: So do you think I have to downgrade my GDAL almost to 1.10 version?

Comment: Gdal 2.0.0dev...that's what I have installed.

Comment: The libgdal-ecw package is designed for GDAL 1.10. I managed to use it with 1.11. It seems that GDAL 2.0 has major changes spoiling the compilation. If you don't want to downgrade, you could install a virtual box with another Ubuntu 12.04 and GDAL 1.10, install ecw support, and transform the files you have to geotiff. BTW: GDAL 2.0 is not from ubuntugis unstable, I guess?

Comment: You guess...It was installed by automatic updates.

Comment: I don't see it in the ubuntugis repositories. Mixing repositories might cause unexpected results...

Comment: Of course...I'm a beginner in the use of Ubuntu and Qgis for ubuntu (not in GIS, I have experience both in arcgis and qgis for windows), but I would like to improve my kills in linux systems...so I'll try to follow your suggestions installing a virtual box (I'm not able now but I 'll try following instructions that I think I can find in the web). Thank you very much for your suggestions!

Comment: For a beginner, it would be better to remove (purge) all GIS stuff, and install the complete GIS suite only from ubuntugis unstable. Then you can decide to play with GDAL 2.0dev and QGIS 2.3.0 (also dev) in a virtual box.

Comment: Ok I'll remove and reinstall all from ubuntugis unstable.

Comment: Sorry, but I have problems uninstalling Gdal...I completely purged all GIS stuff asyou suggested and (in theory) uninstalled gdal wih the command  sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove gdal-bin but if I ask the version with "gdalinfo --version" the system answers GDAL 2.0.0dev, released 2014/04/16.Can I now reinstall qgis from rep  ubuntugis unstable?

Comment: If restarting does not help, you better look out where that gdalinfo still sits on your computer. Maybe from qgis-dev or other packages?