# Enabling ECW for QGIS on Linux Mint 16?

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, linux, ecw

I upgraded to Mint 16 and QGIS 2.4 and unable to get ecw to work following various guides available.

How and why is it so hard?

I run it on a windows machine out of the box.

Comment: Linux Mint 16 is based on Ubuntu 13.10, and both have been deprecated by now. There have been solutions for Ubuntu 12.04 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/installing-ecw-for-qgis-in-ubuntu-12-04 and Ubuntu 14.04 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04 . Both will not work with newer versions of ubuntu and Linux Mint. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209179/how-to-get-ecw-support-on-qgis-2-16-ubuntu-16-04 helps in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

I gather from a few articles that support for ECW (a highly proprietary format) heavily favours Windows installations:

http://www.surfaces.co.il/qgis-on-windows-with-ecw/

I'm not sure how to get the ERDAS support files for Linux, but that's what you'll have to do as noted in the blog post referenced above.