# How to get ECW support on QGIS 2.16 - Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, ecw

after several attempts I am still not able to enable ECW support on QGIS on Ubuntu Xenial.

Before updating to latest version of Ubuntu, solution proposed [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04) worked for me on the same machine, but now it fails to complete the

```
gdal-ecw-build
```

command.

I tried several version of ecw sdk, but it always ends with a series of errors, where the last one is:

```
make: *** [ecwdataset.o] Errore 1
```

I also tried to change the *gdal-ecw-build* script adding a flag as suggested [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW#BinaryECWSDKandGCC5.2), but without any effects.

Some info about my setup:

- GCC version: 5.4
- GDAL version: 2.1
- QGIS version: 2.16.2

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the updated answer to the linked question, there is **NO** pre-packaged solution for newer versions of Ubuntu. The `libgdal-ecw-src` package had been developed for GDAL 1.10, and will not work out-of-the-box with newer GDAL versions, and you will get no GDAL 1.10 for newer Ubuntu versions.

Unless you are able to review the code (supposed you know exactly what it is doing), the only workaround is installing a virtual box with Ubuntu precise (12.04) and GDAL 1.10 just for converting ecw files.

A better way is to self-compile GDAL with ECW support, as described in https://gist.github.com/1papaya/568c4580b1909071696c1cb119101823 and [Can't install support for ECW in QGIS 3.6 / 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04/313388#313388)

Or put Windows in a virtual box, if you have a license for that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint: I was finally able to convert my ecw files into geotiff using a docker instance of ubuntu 12.04. Not too easy to setup, but quicker than virtualbox, now that is running properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have enabled ECW support on QGIS 2.18-ltr on Ubuntu Bionic and it works perfectly.
You have to follow instruction from [this link](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ECW#Howto_install_gdal_with_ECW_support) up to the command `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` not necessary.
After installation of `libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06` and then of the gdal (same version of QGIS) own builted library, because of QGIS installs library in `/usr/lib` but your compiled library will be here `/usr/local/lib`, you have to do backup the n.3  files in `/usr/lib` starting with libgdal.so* and then create a soft link to those with the same name in `/usr/local/lib`. Restart QGIS and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you build it from source?
If so, referring to a working PKGBUILD on arch, you have to build gdal with the correct LDFLAG (in configure):  --with-ecw=/usr.

Extract:

```
build() {
cd "${srcdir}"/$pkgname-$pkgver
export CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fno-strict-aliasing"

# bug #23654
export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -Wl,--as-needed" 

./configure --prefix=/usr --with-netcdf --with-libtiff --with-sqlite3 --with-geotiff \
          --with-mysql --with-python=/usr/bin/python2 --with-curl --with-hdf5 --with-perl --with-geos \
          --with-png --with-poppler --with-spatialite --with-openjpeg --with-libkml \
          --with-ecw=/usr

# workaround for bug #13646
sed -i 's/PY_HAVE_SETUPTOOLS=1/PY_HAVE_SETUPTOOLS=/g' ./GDALmake.opt
sed -i 's/EXE_DEP_LIBS/KILL_EXE_DEP_LIBS/' apps/GNUmakefile

make -j3
```

And also make sure that libecwj2 is properly installed.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:
http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ECW

It's working fine for me on debian (not ubuntu).

Bye.