# How to import ERDAS ECW in QGIS 2.6 using GDAL 1.11?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ubuntu, ecw

I am using Lubuntu 14.10, QGIS 2.6, and Ubuntu GIS(unstable). QGIS was used to use GDAL 1.10, and can import ERDAS ecw format. But after GDAL upgraded to 1.11, QGIS couldn't import ecw images. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you're missing the ECW libraries, on windows they (and MRSID) are separate and need to be downloaded and put into your GDAL_DRIVER_PATH folder (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_DRIVER_PATH).

Comment: There was gdal-ecw-src 1.10, ECW 5.1.1 SDK and GDAL 1.10 with QGIS 2.4 before, and ecw could be imported successfully. After installed QGIS 2.6 and GDAL 1.11 updates,ecw cant be imported now. There was still gdal-ecw-src 1.10 library, I uninstalled this old package and I tryed to built gdal 1.11 with ecw again according  to http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW. It has error as "checking for libNCSEcw.so or libecwj2... configure: error: not found in /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/bin".

Comment: I think it is about old ecw SDK, there is an update of ecw SDK so I will install it and try to build it from source again.

Comment: There were significant changes in the ECW SDK fairly recently, the whole driver has changed. The new ECW is read-only and supports the newest ERDAS ECW changes; possibly the previous (1.10) version may work if it's in the right spot. I can't help (or understand) with linux, sorry, I've been assimilated into Microsoft Windows and know no other.

Comment: I can import ECW on windows7 after installing via OsGeoW. Just problem with linux.

Comment: I have described a kind of hack to get ecw for GDAL 1.11 here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thank you AndreJ. I tryed your hack before posting here. It had an error while building. But after updated ECW SDK 5.1 to 5.2, and retrying your heck, it works!