# ECW support on ubuntu 14.04 - QGIS 2.8.1

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ecw

I've followed instructions for lubuntu 14.04 - QGIS 2.2 ( Answer in [Unable to install ECW support on lubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04) ), adapting to QGIS 2.8.1. No problem to install packets, but result of gdalinfo --formats | grep -i ECW  is:

> ERROR 1: /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI10CNCSThread
>
> ERROR 1: /usr/local/lib/libNCSEcw.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI10CNCSThread

And QGIS doesn't admit ECW still.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Everything is 64 bit, isn't it?

Comment: The only way to get ECW support for both command line utilities and python bindings in 14.04 is to build GDAL from source http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/ubuntu/2014-August/001154.html

Comment: Well.. it's time to learn to build GDAL if there isn't another way