# ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided

Tags: gdal, ubuntu, erdas-imagine, ecw

I downloaded ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1 and tried to use it with GDAL to create ECW files from georeferenced PNG files, but they are not created, it basically complains about:

> ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.

I thought it was free to do so with files smaller than 500 MB (mine is 50 MB). Here the full output:

```
+ gdalwarp -of ECW -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 128 -dstalpha s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.png s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw
Creating output file that is 14185P x 14185L.
Processing input file s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.png.
Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Copying nodata values from source s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.png to destination s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw.
ERROR 6: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 1: SetNoDataValue() not supported for this dataset.
ERROR 6: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 2: SetNoDataValue() not supported for this dataset.
ERROR 6: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 3: SetNoDataValue() not supported for this dataset.
0ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
.ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 5: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 1: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 2: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 3: An error occured while writing a dirty block
```

The only solution to get those keys is to buy that ERDAS software? again, I had the impression that it could be possible.

Any support is very welcomed,

**EDIT 1:**

I want to say that I tried ERDAS SDK 3.3 with GDAL installed from both apt-get and source ways, and none of them have worked so far, it throws an error after running this:

```
gdal_translate -of ECW s05w85.png test.ecw

Input file size is 14185, 14185
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted
```

Moreover, this occurs when I use `gdal_translate`, but using `gdalwarp` keeps saying `Output driver ECW not recognised or does not support`, even though this command line says:

```
gdalwarp --formats | grep -i ecw
ECW -raster- (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x)
JP2ECW -raster,vector- (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)
```

So, I'm confused, is it really possible to create ECW files for free with ERDAS SDK 3.3??

Comment: considered geotiff with jpeg compression?

Comment: I think the base question is 'How do you license ECW compression in GDAL with the new SDK'.. there are new features in ECW for this SDK which makes them quite attractive as a GIS format. Does one just contact Hexagon directly? Is it different by country (like Esri)? Do you need to purchase ERDAS to get the capability? +1 Very good question!

Comment: @NathanW thanks for tip, I've found that this would be a good option, but also JP20OpenJPEG, but I want to know if ECW can really be built with ERDAS SDK 3.3 and GDAL, I've read that gdalwarp can't be used with that format to create files, but it can be possible with gdal_translate.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thanks for your questions, hope someone can build a nice answer including the solution I want and the points you mentioned, so I can mark it as the final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to thank all the support I received from you guys, to AndreJ Luke, Nathan W, Michael Miles-Stimson and user30184. Following all your suggestions finally I could successfully install ECW SDK 3.3, I follow basically what appears in the [OpenStreetMap Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/ECW#Howto_install_gdal_with_ECW_support). I describe below all the steps I used, a small modification from the steps explained in the Wiki:

1. I installed all GIS-related software from the stable/unstable UbuntusGIS repo (qgis, proj, geos, etc). However, I downloaded the latest stable GDAL version from http://download.osgeo.org/gdal/1.11.2/gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz and installed it in /opt (see point 3).
2. I downloaded the libecwj2-3.3 and installed as follows (using only the wcharfix patch):

> ```
> wget http://mirror.ovh.net/gentoo-distfiles/distfiles/libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
> unzip libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
> wget http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/attachment/5001530/0/libecwj2-3.3-wcharfix.patch
> wget http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/raw-attachment/ticket/3366/libecwj2-3.3-NCSPhysicalMemorySize-Linux.patch
> wget http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/raw-attachment/ticket/3162/libecwj2-3.3-msvc90-fixes.patch
> patch -p0 < libecwj2-3.3-wcharfix.patch
>   locate NCSPrefsXML.cpp | grep libecwj2-3.3
>   (when you found it, just re-run the previous patch command line and paste the full path+CPPname found with locate)
> patch -p0 < libecwj2-3.3-msvc90-fixes.patch
> patch -p0 < libecwj2-3.3-NCSPhysicalMemorySize-Linux.patch
>   locate malloc.c | grep libecwj2-3.3
>   (when you found it, just re-run the previous patch command line and paste the full path+Cname found with locate)
> cd libecwj2-3.3/
> ./configure
> make 
> make install
> ```

3. I installed GDAL-1.11.2 as follows:

> ```
> tar xzvf gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz
> sudo mv /home/gery/Desktop/gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz .
> sudo chmod a+wx gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz 
> sudo tar xzxf gdal-1.11.2.tar.gz 
> cd gdal-1.11.2/
> sudo ./configure --with-ecw=/usr/local --with-python --with-proj --with-geos
> sudo make
> sudo make install
> ```

Hope this helps!

PS.

> $ uname -a
>
> Linux 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html

```
For those still using the ECW 3.3 SDK, images less than 500MB may be compressed for free, while larger images require licensing from ERDAS. See the licensing agreement and the LARGE_OK option.
```

So you are out of luck with the 5.1 SDK without a valid license.

Depending on your OS, you might still catch a copy of the old SDK somewhere.

**EDIT**

http://www.gisinternals.com/archive.php has Windows builds which were compiled with the ecw 3.3 SDK up to GDAL version 1.10.0 (and some MSVC2005 builds of newer versions too).

Comment: Exactly. Windows users can acquire ECW SDK 3.3 based plugin from http://gisinternals.com/sdk. It is more difficult if you want to build the plugin yourself because Hexagon Geospatial does not deliver 3.3. SDK any more.

Comment: @AndreJ thanks for the answer, that was missing then, anyone willing to share ECW 3.3. SDK for ubuntu?

Comment: Try this blog entry: http://blog.technokrat.nl/2012/11/28/making-sure-gdal-works-with-ecw-libecw-under-linux/. The download link seems to work. You might need an older version of GDAL too: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04

Comment: Thanks for that, it installed so `gdalwarp --formats | grep -i ecw`, `ECW (rw): ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (SDK 3.x) \n JP2ECW (rw+v): ERDAS JPEG2000 (SDK 3.x)`, but a simple test: `gdalwarp -of ECW s05w5_200_200.png test.ecw` says `Output driver 'ECW' not recognised or does not support direct output file creation.  The following format drivers are configured`. `gdalwarp --formats` says the same as `gdalinfo`.

Comment: @Gery, ECW does not support CREATE, only CREATECOPY. Workaround is to `gdalwarp` to VRT first, then `gdal_translate` to ECW.

Comment: If you can read ecw files, the driver should work.

Comment: @Luke it seems that ERDAS driver doesn't work correctly, with gdal_translate on VRT I keep getting `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted`

Comment: @Gery the ECW SDK 3.3 is very old (released 2006), very buggy (as you have just found) and does not support newer ECW formats. I wouldn't bother with it. If you want to create ECW, buy an ERDAS license and use the latest SDK, otherwise use the OpenJPEG2000 driver and create JP2s or Geotiffs with YCBCR JPEG compression which compress almost as small as ECWs.

Comment: @Luke thanks for the info, still I need to convert my VRT files (quite nicely done actually) to ECW, so far I don't have any chances to buy an ERDAS license, that's why I'd like to have the ECW SDK 3.3 working.

Comment: @Luke the problem that it throws `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'   what():  basic_string::_S_create Aborted`, so ECW cannot be created, that's the actual issue.

Comment: @Gery  Did you apply the patches referenced in the [wiki](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW)? In particular the one discussed in [this ticket](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4868).