# Is it possible get pixel value with only PyQGIS and not GDAL?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, pyqgis, pixel

It seems that gdal can caused in some crashes in QGIS, specific in used for raster layers (such as links : [QGIS crashes on close if data was read through GDAL in Python Console](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/13061)  or [GDAL/QGIS broken Ubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154343/gdal-qgis-broken-ubuntu-14-04) or [Why close QGIS for extract pixel values by GDAL?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247382/why-close-qgis-for-extract-pixel-values-by-gdal). 
So Is it possible to get pixel values only with pyqgis and without gdal?

Comment: is http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html#query-values what you're after?

Comment: When you have it working can you answer your own question with some of your code, I'm sure that other users might have a similar problem and would like to see how it's done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get pixel values without gdal; only PyQGIS. Easier way is with a **QgsRasterBlock** object. This is the code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer() #in my case, a 20x20 raster

provider = layer.dataProvider()

extent = provider.extent()

rows = layer.height()
cols = layer.width()

block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print block.value(i,j),
    print
```

After running the code at Python Console of QGIS, I got:

```
27.0 17.0 48.0 60.0 32.0 53.0 73.0 5.0 94.0 35.0 18.0 31.0 35.0 63.0 54.0 26.0 79.0 17.0 3.0 98.0
32.0 44.0 7.0 9.0 54.0 52.0 12.0 19.0 75.0 26.0 27.0 28.0 36.0 58.0 25.0 83.0 83.0 67.0 70.0 6.0
27.0 17.0 44.0 63.0 82.0 76.0 64.0 69.0 42.0 52.0 81.0 4.0 46.0 37.0 97.0 86.0 88.0 44.0 17.0 16.0
36.0 70.0 53.0 91.0 34.0 9.0 90.0 47.0 39.0 23.0 30.0 27.0 36.0 89.0 99.0 48.0 23.0 55.0 56.0 77.0
75.0 96.0 75.0 64.0 36.0 72.0 55.0 87.0 35.0 56.0 23.0 6.0 97.0 58.0 97.0 54.0 14.0 93.0 9.0 54.0
41.0 58.0 52.0 3.0 96.0 45.0 32.0 85.0 32.0 98.0 9.0 26.0 63.0 20.0 83.0 10.0 67.0 24.0 58.0 19.0
61.0 5.0 15.0 17.0 53.0 57.0 57.0 59.0 79.0 43.0 7.0 65.0 83.0 65.0 32.0 59.0 22.0 24.0 25.0 22.0
66.0 60.0 3.0 94.0 53.0 93.0 10.0 8.0 24.0 16.0 92.0 95.0 79.0 42.0 97.0 45.0 82.0 87.0 31.0 8.0
2.0 40.0 34.0 5.0 6.0 37.0 9.0 83.0 28.0 11.0 54.0 84.0 35.0 30.0 46.0 24.0 49.0 15.0 30.0 36.0
30.0 45.0 65.0 64.0 18.0 49.0 78.0 70.0 83.0 64.0 48.0 73.0 69.0 2.0 69.0 1.0 30.0 20.0 45.0 74.0
7.0 93.0 76.0 96.0 60.0 84.0 7.0 81.0 79.0 6.0 47.0 80.0 9.0 61.0 43.0 19.0 53.0 100.0 28.0 49.0
77.0 4.0 79.0 84.0 65.0 14.0 91.0 62.0 41.0 1.0 78.0 26.0 100.0 66.0 37.0 8.0 96.0 51.0 83.0 94.0
100.0 28.0 77.0 7.0 3.0 72.0 82.0 97.0 3.0 25.0 64.0 66.0 25.0 75.0 54.0 29.0 15.0 36.0 25.0 57.0
7.0 63.0 64.0 46.0 41.0 13.0 6.0 34.0 55.0 32.0 99.0 87.0 12.0 100.0 9.0 31.0 48.0 22.0 7.0 52.0
45.0 43.0 9.0 17.0 39.0 98.0 20.0 51.0 80.0 91.0 52.0 18.0 40.0 39.0 5.0 97.0 74.0 5.0 9.0 99.0
67.0 53.0 24.0 67.0 32.0 17.0 35.0 98.0 37.0 68.0 18.0 31.0 71.0 95.0 59.0 100.0 97.0 60.0 22.0 6.0
97.0 73.0 69.0 93.0 13.0 87.0 29.0 69.0 10.0 62.0 35.0 26.0 62.0 51.0 30.0 15.0 25.0 62.0 1.0 61.0
59.0 53.0 22.0 74.0 5.0 52.0 13.0 29.0 14.0 18.0 9.0 99.0 70.0 3.0 53.0 100.0 39.0 20.0 73.0 30.0
66.0 72.0 92.0 26.0 77.0 67.0 74.0 60.0 55.0 68.0 71.0 61.0 32.0 72.0 100.0 49.0 80.0 74.0 8.0 1.0
53.0 4.0 82.0 72.0 86.0 82.0 92.0 22.0 52.0 8.0 31.0 30.0 6.0 2.0 14.0 73.0 34.0 60.0 84.0 96.0
```

I corroborated, with help of Value Tool plugin, that values extracted were correct.

Comment: Thanks, It's simple but effective code.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @Michael Stimson in above and QGIS document (http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/raster.html#query-values).
In below example it is possible to get pixel values without gdal.

```
from qgis.core import *

def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth/2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight /2)
    return QgsPoint(xp, yp)

# Open tif file
ds = QgsRasterLayer("/Data/Sample_Polygon.tif","Study")

pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()

pntRstList = []

for i in range(0, src_cols):
    for j in range(0, src_rows):
        rspnt = pixel2coord(i,j)
        pntRstList.append(rspnt)

for x, y in pntRstList:
    ident = ds.dataProvider().identify(QgsPoint(x, y), 
    QgsRaster.IdentifyFormatValue)
    if ident.isValid():
        print ident.results()
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to get pixel values without gdal, only PyQGIS, but easier way is with a **QgsRasterBlock** object.

Answer (score 1):

the first solution is a really good one! I just would like to propose instead of print or instead of put it in a list like in the second solution, put the values in numpy array. If you are planning to work with large maps is better to take this approach once the numpy array is much faster.

```
    from qgis.core import *
    import numpy as np

    def GetValuePixels(layer):
        provider = layer.dataProvider()

        extent = provider.extent()

        rows = layer.height()
        cols = layer.width()

        block = provider.block(1, extent, cols, rows)
        values = np.zeros(shape=(rows,cols)) #Creates space in the memory to avoid spend time...

        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                values[i,j] = block.value(i,j)

        return values
```

thanks!