# Is it possible to import .ecw images into QGIS 2.10 for Ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ecw

We want to import .ecw images. We have done it using QGIS 2.8 for Windows in the past, but we can't using QGIS 2.10 for Ubuntu

Comment: Please edit your question to include any error messages you received. Where/when exactly is it failing?

Comment: ECW isn't an open-source format so the drivers can't be shipped with QGIS or GDAL... you'll need to install them yourself. You might want to check out [ECW for Qgis 1.8 in Ubuntu 12.04](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/ecw-for-qgis-1-8-in-ubuntu-12-04/27398#27398) for instructions

Comment: @StevenKay there seems to be no problem to ship the ECW driver with OSGEO4W or standalone Windows builds. It is only a packaging problem, since it once worked from the ubuntugis-unstable repository running GDAL 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is currently not possible to install the GDAL ECW driver on current QGIS and Ubuntu versions in an easy way.

There is an ECW driver in the ubuntugis-unstable repository that works with GDAL 1.10 on Ubuntu 14.04, but needs a hack to make it running under GDAL 1.11: [Unable to install ECW support on lubuntu 14.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04)

Unfortunately, it does not seem to work anymore with newer ubuntu versions. If building GDAL from source is no option for you, I suggest to install a virtual box with ubuntu 14.04 and try my workaround. Or put Windows in the box (if you have a license for that) and just use it for transforming ecw files to Geotiff for further processing.