# Geoserver ecw plugin problem

Tags: geoserver, gdal, ecw

I am trying to publish some ecw files with geoserver 2.7.2 on ubuntu 15.04 x64. I downloaded gdal plugin, gdal_data and native libraries for image-io 1.1.11 and set environment variables; GDAL_DATA, LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

I can see new store types when adding new one (ECW, EHdr, JP2ECW etc.). But when I try to save an ECW store with a valid ecw file which I tested with ArcMap, geoserver crashes with this error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted (core dumped)

Do you have any idea about this problem?

Comment: what does gdalinfo show for the file?

Comment: It gives same error: gdalinfo: /home/GDAL_PATH/gdal192-Ubuntu12-gcc4.6.3-x86_64/libgdal.so.1: no version information available (required by gdalinfo)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Where did you get the gdal plugin from?

Comment: I downloaded native plugins from http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/1.1.X/1.1.11/native/gdal/linux. Followed these steps: http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html

Comment: Followed these (http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/102088/50083) steps and managed to run gdalinfo (gdalinfo ecwfile.ecw) from command line. But when geoserver starting it gives this error: ERROR 1: /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.11/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.so: undefined symbol: GDALRegisterMe
ERROR 1: /usr/lib/gdalplugins/1.11/gdal_ECW_JP2ECW.so: undefined symbol: _ZTI14GDALPamDataset. Getting same error when importing gdal in python.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I managed to run ecw plugin inside geoserver version 2.7.2

- Downloaded libecw source from http://meuk.technokrat.nl/libecwj2-3.3-2006-09-06.zip
- Applied this patch https://github.com/makinacorpus/libecw/blob/master/Source/C/NCSUtil/NCSPrefsXML.cpp.rej
- Ran ./configure, make and sudo make install commands to build.
- Override generated libs over image-io-ext libs.  Make sure the path to the newly compiled .so's are in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable **before** the existing ones (present in geoserver gdal documentation).
- The other steps told in geoserver gdal documentation (cant post more than 2 links) are valid.

Comment: This worked for me, except the patch didn't quite apply. Here's my version: https://gist.github.com/stevage/b0bdade278fa066d4082369f95d47670

Comment: Also for anyone else a little bit unclear, the "Override generated libs" line means just creating a line like this in your Tomcat init script: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/mnt/gdal/ecw/libecwj2-3.3:/mnt/gdal`