# Ubuntu Linux | Unable to configure ECW extenion in Geoserver 2.14.1 (war file)

Tags: geoserver, gdal, ecw, mrsid

We are using Ubuntu Linux 16.04, Geo-server war file 2.14.1 & Tomcat 8.5 (64 bit)

We have configured Geoserver in tomcat and trying to configure MrSID & ECW plugins

Steps Completed :-

1.GDAL ver. 1.9.2 installed

2.Geoserver Stable Plugins are added respective directory

3.Set an reference path's in Ubuntu Linux

4.Followed [this steps](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html) from Geo-server site

5.Now MrSID extension works fine and for ECW extension shows error "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what():  basic_string::_S_create" & geoserver stops

6.Researching on this & it looks like its not supporting  for latest Linux version as pre [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209179/how-to-get-ecw-support-on-qgis-2-16-ubuntu-16-04/212622) (because if its not working for QGIS then doubt it will work for geoserver)

Tried [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158828/geoserver-ecw-plugin-problem) and its steps

7.Is their any license required for this ? ([reference site)](https://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/github/imageio-ext/releases/native/gdal/1.9.2/linux/notes_on_ECW_and_JP2ECW.txt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sunil, yes, you have to pay a licence so Hexagon corporation in order to legally use the ECW decoding libraries on a server (they are free for desktop usage instead).