# ECW files not visible in qgis browser (or qbrowser as executed in console)?

Tags: qgis, ecw

version: 2.4.0-1ubuntu2

I'm following a web tutorial at lynda.com about QGIS.
In one of the first videos I see there's this preview of raster files.

There's the `.dem` files and the `.ecw` files among the tutorial example files. I can preview the `.dem` files as in the video, but unlike the authors of the tutorial I cannot preview the `.ecw` files.

Additionally, when I try to open a `.ecw` file with qgis (not qbrowser), I get the following message:

> The layer whateverthepathis/552B.ecw is not a valid layer and can not be added to the map

When I open a `.dem` file instead, no error message is displayed and the layer is added just fine.

Is there something I need to setup in order to be able to preview those files and add their layers to the map?
Is it a bug of this particular version?

I'm just getting started with qgis and with GIS software in general.

Answer (score 4):

ECW file support is not included by default due to licensing issues.  There is a tutorial for adding ECW support to QGIS on Ubuntu Linux.

See here:

https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/adding-ecw-support-in-qgis/

Basically you need to build lib-gdal-ecw and download an appropriate SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work anymore for recent versions of ubuntu and GDAL, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04