# ECW support on QGIS version 2.14.4-Essen (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, ecw

someone know how to abilitate ECW support on QGIS version 2.14.4-Essen (Ubuntu 14.04)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94870/unable-to-install-ecw-support-on-lubuntu-14-04. Since QGIS Essen is built against GDAL 2.1.0, you may be out of luck with your configuration. You might well try a Virtual box with ubuntu precise and GDAL 1.10 to be able to transform the ECW files to something that can be used in QGIS. Or try wine or Windows in a virtual box.

Comment: Thanks AndreJ, I'm already transforming ECW in GeoTIFF using a different machine. But I would to like to avoid this.

Comment: I would like it too, but not yet found a good up-to-date solution.