# ecw on windows 7 qgis 1.8

Tags: qgis, ecw

I used 1.7.4 qgis release on Windows 7, by which it was possible to manage ECWfiles; after passing to 1.8 release, I couldn't deal with an ECW file: it tells me that .ecw is not a supported kind of file on QuantumGis. What can I do? Is there anyone that could help me?

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to install the ecw plugin from Erdas. Perhaps you did that for 1.7.4? Erdas will ask for your details but it is no problem.

Depends on how you installed qgis, see

[Quantum GIS and ECW images?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1892/quantum-gis-and-ecw-images/1899#1899)

Comment: Done, but it doesn't work and in addition I didn't install the ecw plugin from Erdas installing 1.7.4 (the ecw plugin is automatically installed)

Comment: Did you use the OSGEO installer to set up QGIS 1.8?

Comment: Yes I did, but it didn't work: Now I solved the problem simply setting up as environment variable the path to 1.9 GDAL